# How can QuickCheck test all properties for each sample

Tags: haskell, template-haskell, quickcheck

...instead of generating 100 new random samples for each property?

My testsuite contains the TemplateHaskell hack explained here [1] to
test all functions named prop_*.  Running the test program prints

```
=== prop_foo from tests/lala.lhs:20 ===
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.

=== prop_bar from tests/lala.lhs:28 ===
+++ OK, passed 100 tests.
```

and it looks like going through 100 random samples for each of the
properties.

Problemis: Generating the samples is quite expensive, checking the
properties is not.  So I'd like to have a means to pass each random
sample to each of the prop_* functions instead of creating new
(#properties * 100) many samples.

Is there anything like that built in?  Actually, I think I'd need a
replacement for the splice

```
$(forAllProperties)
```

in

```
main :: IO ()
main
  = do args <- parseArgs <$> getArgs
       s <- $(forAllProperties) $ quickCheckWithResult args
       s ? return () $ exitFailure
  where
    parseArgs as
      = null as ? stdArgs $ stdArgs{ maxSuccess = read $ head as }
```

---

[1] [Simple haskell unit testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5683911/), and
    [QuickCheck exit status on failures, and cabal integration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8976488/)

Comment: `propAllOfThem x = all ($x) [prop1, prop2, prop3]`?

Comment: @DanielWagner: If you actually meant `($x)`, then I don't understand it (Recall: Template Haskell!).  If you meant `($ x)` instead, then no, this has several drawbacks: The properties are not collected automatically, and if one fails I do not see which one, QuickCheck only reports `prop_AllOfThem`.

Answer (score 0):

In this post you can see how to group tests

[Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22127558/haskell-io-monads-quickcheck/)

That user provides a very simple example of use **Test.Tasty.QuickCheck**

Using *testProperty* and *testGroup* you can pass each random sample to each property

In the next link you can check the *hackage* of this package

[Test.Tasty.QuickCheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-quickcheck-0.8.4/docs/Test-Tasty-QuickCheck.html)

Comment: Does not solve my problem, see comment to @DanielWagner above.